# Using the hypergeometric distribution to solve Banach's match problem

Tags: probability

I am trying to see whether I can use the hypergeometric distribution to solve Banach's match problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_matchbox_problem

Since we have the same probability of selecting matches from either pocket I think it should apply.

My idea is as follows:

If you have $N_1$ matches in one pocket and $N_2$ matches in the second pocket, then you have $N_1$ + $N_2$ total matches. First we look at the possibility that $N_2$ is empty. That means that you need to have selected $N_2$ matches out of the $N_2$ matches you had, and then $N_1 - k$ matches out of the $N_1$ matches you had. Finally, you need to select pocket 2 again, which happens with probability 0.5. This means that

$$P(N_1 = k | N_2 = 0) = \frac { \binom {N_1} {N_1-k} \binom {N_2} {N_2} }{\binom {N_1 + N_2} {N_1 + N_2 -k}} \cdot \frac 1 2$$

If we now suppose pocket 1 is the one with the empty box, then by the same reasoning,

$$P(N_2 = k | N_1 = 0) = \frac { \binom {N_2} {N_2-k} \binom {N_1} {N_1} }{\binom {N_1 + N_2} {N_1 + N_2 -k}} \cdot \frac 1 2$$

Because both pockets have the same amount of matches, the total probability is:

$$\frac { \binom {N_2} {N_2-k} \binom {N_1} {N_1} }{\binom {N_1 + N_2} {N_1 + N_2 -k}}$$

I get an answer very close to what I would get if I were to model this using the traditional negative binomial approach, but not exactly. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: "Since we have the same probability of selecting matches from either pocket I think it should apply." - Hypergeometric probability is used for problems like the following: a box contains 5 red and 10 green balls.  Seven balls are selected at random from the box.  What is the probability that exactly 2 of them are red?  In problems of this type, it is not the case that selecting red and selecting green have the same probability.  So I'm not sure why you say that the hypergeometric distribution ought to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two questions: (1) Should some of your $N_1$s and $N_2$s be $N$s?  You seem to be using each of $N_1$ and $N_2$ as both a constant and as a variable.  Do you mean for there to be the same number of matches in each pocket initially?  If so, I would call that number $N.$  (2) Are you sure your method gives a value that is numerically close to the correct answer?  I tried with a number of different parameter values, and was getting very different answers.  Can you say what parameters you tried?

Now for my answer.  The difference is between picking with and without replacement.  One can model Banach's problem as follows: one has an urn containing $N$ tickets marked $L$ and $N$ tickets marked $R.$  One selects a ticket from the urn; if it is marked $L,$ one takes a match from the left pocket; if it is marked $R,$ one takes a match from the right pocket; one then replaces the ticket in the urn.  One then computes the probability that on pick number $2N-k+1,$ one first discovers that the pocket one is required to pick from is empty.

What you are computing is similar, except that the tickets are not replaced in the urn.  This has a number of consequences.  In your version, the number of tickets with each label tracks the number of matches in the corresponding pocket; in the traditional version, there are always $N$ tickets with each label in the urn.  This means that, in your version, if one pocket is nearly empty and the other still has plenty of matches, it becomes very unlikely that one will pick from the nearly empty pocket.  This significantly reduces the probability that one will empty one pocket while the other still contains many matches.  In fact, strictly speaking, once one pocket is empty, one cannot try to pick from that pocket again because the number of tickets corresponding to that pocket remaining in the urn is zero.  Therefore, the situation described in the original problem of trying to pick from the empty pocket cannot actually occur in your version.  You have got around this by setting the probability of picking from the empty pocket to be $1/2$ in the last step, but this is an artifice, since in general the probability of picking from that pocket was not equal to $1/2$ earlier in the experiment.

Comment: yeah I guess the notation wasn't clear :) I tried with 0.5, it looked fairly close. Anyway, thanks for your answer!